# Как убрать текст при нажатии на поиск в toolbar?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar

При нажатии на кнопку поиска в toolbar контейнер текста уменьшается и текст растягивается вниз. Помогите решить проблему.

[image: кнопка поиска не нажата]
[image: кнопка поиска нажата]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".menu.MainMenuActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/background"
            android:fontFamily="@font/manrope_bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main_menu" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу проблему. С чем конкретно у вас возникла трудность? Что мешает просто скрыть заголовок: `textView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`? Добавьте детали в вопрос, отредактируйте его, нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1484442/edit) под вопросом.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю и Ваш поиск представляет собой пункт меню с `app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"`, то можно сделать так

```java
val menuSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.<ID_меню-итема_поиска>);
val searchView = (SearchView) menuSearchItem.getActionView();
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(view -> {
    <код, убирающий текст>
});
searchView.setOnCloseListener(() -> {
    <код, возвращающий текст>
});
```